# Amazon Device SDK (MQTT Client) Disconnecting without detecting the disconnection

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot

I'm using the Amazon Device SDK in a NodeJS project. I'm specifically using the MQTT broker and client. Last week, things were working fine. This week, my application is having connectivity issues. I had not done anything to any code related to connectivity between then and now.

According to logging on the AWS side, my client connects, sends a message (and may receive a few) , and then is disconnecting.

According to my Node client, the client is connecting and is remaining connected. On the client end, there are no problems detected. I believe that because AWS is interpreting the client as being disconnected and thus is not routing messages to it. To simplify things, I have my client only displaying status messages.  The following ths what I've reduced my client to. I'm still observing the issue.

Sometimes if I send a few messages as soon as the application starts up, it will receive several of them. I have a very short window until it becomes "disconnected" (according to the AWS logging).

Any idea what would cause this?

```
this.device = awsIot.device({
    host,
    keyPath: `${process.cwd()}/certificates/2399999999-private.pem.key`,
    certPath: `${process.cwd()}/certificates/2399999999-certificate.pem.crt`,
    caPath: `${process.cwd()}/certificates/AmazonRootCA1.pem`,
    clientId: config.clientId,
    autoResubscribe: true,
    maximumReconnectTimeMs: 1600,
    keepalive: 300,
    debug: config.mqttConnection.debug,
    enableMetrics: config.mqttConnection.enableMetrics        
});


this.device.on('error', error => {
    console.error('MQTT client error: ', error);
});

this.device.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.error(`Disconnected from MQTT broker ${host}`);
});

this.device.on('message', async (topic, payload) => {
    log(`Received MQTT message: topic "${topic}", payload "${payload.toString()}"`);


});

this.device.on('close', () => { 
    console.log('close')
});

this.device.on('error', () => { 
    console.log('error')
});

this.device.on('reconnect', () => { 
    console.log('reconnect')
});

this.device.on('offline', () => { 
    console.log('offline❌')
});

this.device.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('connected')
    this.device.subscribe('rootTopic/#');
});
```

From the AWS Logs I have the following.

```
[
{
    "timestamp": "2021-09-09 01:25:08.930",
    "logLevel": "INFO",
    "traceId": "7a03fe42-8b6d-0b8e-8bca-0a404e40f0ef",
    "accountId": "0000",
    "status": "Success",
    "eventType": "Connect",
    "protocol": "MQTT",
    "clientId": "000-000-000000",
    "principalId": "aaaa",
    "sourceIp": "73.43.xxx.xxx",
    "sourcePort": 55961
},
{
    "timestamp": "2021-09-09 01:25:09.056",
    "logLevel": "INFO",
    "traceId": "7e965df3-84c8-562b-51b7-48f7f8b851b5",
    "accountId": "0000",
    "status": "Success",
    "eventType": "Subscribe",
    "protocol": "MQTT",
    "topicName": "experiencemanager/#",
    "clientId": "000-000-000000",
    "principalId": "aaaa",
    "sourceIp": "73.43.xxx.xxx",
    "sourcePort": 55961
},
{
    "timestamp": "2021-09-09 01:25:29.389",
    "logLevel": "INFO",
    "traceId": "6d81fb8e-521c-f91c-aea2-3ab3e4f47549",
    "accountId": "0000",
    "status": "Success",
    "eventType": "Disconnect",
    "protocol": "MQTT",
    "clientId": "000-000-000000",
    "principalId": "aaaa",
    "sourceIp": "73.43.xxx.xxx",
    "sourcePort": 55961,
    "disconnectReason": "CONNECTION_LOST"
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer per se, but I have found the problem I'm encountering to be rooted in Electron's timer. The timer functionality in Electron ceases to function. With no timer, the AWS sdk is not able to detect disconnected or operate on certain queues.

I have more digging to do. But it is not a problem with the Amazon SDK itself.